# Meteor - Accounts.forgotPassword triggers internal server error whil Email.send is working fine

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm meeting an issue on Meteor with Accounts.forgotPassword method.
My email smtp is well set up as I can use Email.send() without any issue once app is deployed.

But strangely, accounts.forgotPassword return an internal error.
When looking at the logs I have this error :

> Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' Error: Mail command failed: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable

I do not really understand why I would have mailbox unavailable error with Accounts.forgotPassword but not with Email.send()

Does anyone already met that kind of issues ?
I have already searched on the web for any clues but did not find anything :(

*FYI I use ionos smtp*

Comment: Hi, can you please add which Meteor release and Accounts package version you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Email.send` is working, I assume your MAIL_URL is set correctly, but your `Accounts.emailTemplates` is not. From https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html:

> In addition to configuring the email package’s MAIL_URL, it is critical that you set proper values (specifically the from address) in Accounts.emailTemplates to ensure proper delivery of e-mails!

Comment: Hi Christian ah I did not see this I'll check it tonight and get back to you to confirm thanks for the clue !

Comment: Hi again you were right I did not see this warning message on the doc now I did receive the reset email.Thanks a lot :)